# Ruby grep with line number

Tags: ruby, grep

What could be the best way of getting the matching lines **with the line numbers** using Ruby's `Enumerable#grep` method. (as we use `-n` or `--line-number` switch with grep command).

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing your use case for this.

Comment: I'm curious why `\`grep -n target file_to_search\`` isn't good enough. It'll be extremely fast and supports all of grep's features.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Yeah that's true, but I'd like to have a ruby solution for platform independence.

Comment: @Phrogz: My use case is i am picking a particular pattern from erb files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enumerable#grep doesn't let you do that, at least by default. Instead, I came up with:

```
text = 'now is the time
for all good men
to come to the aid
of their country'

regex = /aid/

hits = text.lines.with_index(1).inject([]) { |m,i| m << i if (i[0][regex]); m }
hits # => [["to come to the aid\n", 3]]
```

Comment: +1 as I found this answer is closest to the one I was looking for. I had to change it a bit to make it 1.8.7 compatible. Later I found it'd be great, for my requirement, if the result comes as a hash, having line numbers as keys and lines as values. I'm putting that as an answer for the record.

Comment: It helps us a lot if you know what you want before writing the question, and ask for that. Your end result would have been trivial to add and then would have been exactly what you were looking for. And, actually, my answer would have been better.

Comment: Couldn't agree more the Tin Man. But you know, sometime you refine your idea after walking a good amount of steps towards the solution :)

Answer (score 7):

maybe something like this:

```
module Enumerable
  def lgrep(pattern)
    map.with_index.select{|e,| e =~ pattern}
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm just curious about this `|e,|` notation you're using. What exactly does this mean?

Comment: It throws away the second arguments (it's not needed). If I had omitted it, e would have turned into an array of both args.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't elegant or efficient, but why not just number the lines before grepping?

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly good, common-sense answer. Don't do it again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can kludge it in Ruby 1.8.6 like so:

```
require 'enumerator'
class Array
  def grep_with_index(regex)
    self.enum_for(:each_with_index).select {|x,i| x =~ regex}
  end
end
arr = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Gah']
arr.grep_with_index(/o/) # => [[0, 'Foo']]
arr.grep_with_index(/a/) # => [[1, 'Bar'], [2, 'Gah']]
```

Or if you're looking for tips on writing a grep-like utility in Ruby.  Something like this should work:

```
def greplines(filename, regex)
  lineno = 0
  File.open(filename) do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
      puts "#{lineno += 1}: #{line}" if line =~ regex
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> lines=["one", "two", "tests"]
=> ["one", "two", "tests"]
>> lines.grep(/test/){|x| puts "#{lines.index(x)+1}, #{x}" }
3, tests
```

Answer (score 1):

To mash up the Tin Man's and ghostdog74's answers

```
text = 'now is the time
for all good men
to come to the aid
of their country'

regex = /aid/

text.lines.grep(/aid/){|x| puts "#{text.lines.find_index(x)+1}, #{x}" }
# => 3, to come to the aid
```

Answer (score 1):

A modification to the solution given by the Tin Man. This snippet will return a hash having line numbers as keys, and matching lines as values. This one also works in ruby 1.8.7.

```
text = 'now is the time
for all good men
to come to the aid
of their country'

regex = /aid/


hits = text.lines.each_with_index.inject({}) { |m, i| m.merge!({(i[1]+1) => i[0].chomp}) if (i[0][regex]); m}

hits #=> {3=>"to come to the aid"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put text in a file

### test.log

```
 now is the time
 for all good men
 to come to the aid
 of their country
```

---

Command line (alternative of grep or awk command )

```
ruby -ne ' puts $_  if $_=~/to the/' test.log
```

Try this also

```
ruby -na -e ' puts $F[2] if $_=~/the/' test.log
```

Similarly

```
ruby -na -e ' puts $_.split[2] if $_=~/the/' test.log
```

This is similar to awk command.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

`lines.find_index{ |l| l=~ regex }`.

Comment: This is more elegant than any of the other solutions. Wish I could upvote. Stack Overflow needs to be more dynamic and adaptable to changing times/paradigms.